# apply shift_right or shift_left on multiple lines

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

i have a source viewer. In this, i need to shift multiple lines to right, when tab is pressed and remove tab, on these lines, when Shift+Tab is pressed. Below is my code. I m not sure how to proceed further. Can you please suggest how this can be done.

```
public class MyViewer extends SourceViewer {
 public MyViewer(final Composite parent, final int styles) {
 super(parent, null, styles);

 final Font font = JFaceResources.getFont(MyConstants.EDITOR_TEXT_FONT);
 getTextWidget().setFont(font);

 getTextWidget().addTraverseListener(new TraverseListener() {

    public void keyTraversed(final TraverseEvent e) {
     if (e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT || e.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_PREVIOUS) {
        if (areMultipleLinesSelected()) {
            e.doit = true;
            final ITextSelection textSelection = (ITextSelection) FastCodeTemplateViewer.this.getSelection();
         //what to do after this, to apply, SHIFT_LEFT or SHIFT_RIGHT, on the selected content
        }


}); 

@Override
   public void setDocument(final IDocument document) {
    ...
}

@Override
  public void setHyperlinkPresenter(final IHyperlinkPresenter hyperlinkPresenter) throws    IllegalStateException {
   ...
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SourceViewer` already defines an operation to shift text left and right. There is no need to extend the SourceViewer. The operations can be invoked from the traverse listener just like this:

```java
sourceViewer.getTextWidget().addTraverseListener( new TraverseListener() {
  @Override
  public void keyTraversed( TraverseEvent event ) {
    if( event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_NEXT ) {
      if( sourceViewer.canDoOperation( ITextOperationTarget.SHIFT_RIGHT ) ) {
        sourceViewer.doOperation( ITextOperationTarget.SHIFT_RIGHT );
      }
      event.doit = false;
    } else if( event.detail == SWT.TRAVERSE_TAB_PREVIOUS ) {
      if( sourceViewer.canDoOperation( ITextOperationTarget.SHIFT_LEFT ) ) {
        sourceViewer.doOperation( ITextOperationTarget.SHIFT_LEFT );
      }
      event.doit = false;
    }
  }
} );
```

Setting the `doit` flag to `false` prevents the traveral from taking place, i.e. transferring the focus to the previous/next control.

This has the side effect that the selection is replaced by a tab character after it was shifted. To prevent this, a `VerifyKeyListener` can help if it suppresses the tab key if anything is selected.

```java
textViewer.prependVerifyKeyListener( new VerifyKeyListener() {
  @Override
  public void verifyKey( VerifyEvent verifyEvent ) {
    if( verifyEvent.keyCode == SWT.TAB && sourceViewer.getSelectedRange().y > 0 ) {
      verifyEvent.doit = false;
    }
  }
} );
```

You may figure out a less 'hacky' solution if you study the code of the Eclipse Text Editor which also offers this feature. In particualr the interaction between `ShiftAction` and `TextEditor`.